# "数値 + 単位" で価格を表す列を、数値順でソートしたい

Tags: mysql, mariadb

外国人なので日本語のレベルは申し訳ございません。

他のウェブサイトからデータを取得してデータベースに入れましたが "Price (販売価格)" という列を価格順にソートしたいです。

ここで問題なのは、"6,690万円(1戸)" のようにセルの中に数字と一緒に日本語の文字も含まれており、恐らくちゃんとソートが機能していません。

対象の列は "LongText" 、テーブルの文字コードは "Utf8mb4 Unicode ci" です。

MySQLで上記のようなPriceの列をどうすればソートできますか？

**試したコード:**

```
SELECT * FROM `estates` ORDER BY LPAD(lower(price), 10,0) ASC
```

```
SELECT price FROM `estates` ORDER BY number+0 ASC
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 値が「○○万円」の場合と「○○万円～××万円」の様に、複数の表記が混在している部分が少し対応が面倒そうです。固定の(余分な)文字列であれば、それを除去してソートする方法はあるようです。 - http://blog.higty.xyz/archives/384/

Comment: `1000万円(1戸)`と`1000万円(1戸)～1500万円(1戸)`と`500万円(1戸)～1000万円(1戸)`の3つのデータがどのように並ぶことを期待していますか？

Answer (score 0):

データベースにレコード作成する時に数値型に変換しておいてはいかがでしょう